# Waiting for invisible elements not on the page

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, selenium, xpath

I am trying to scrape off of this webpage with following [script](https://pastebin.com/z8VPiPgc).

I cannot wait for this element and it does not scrape correctly.

```
clickMe = wait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ('//a[@class='style-scope match-pop-market']'))))
```

The element is correct in Chrome inspect.

```
//a[@class='style-scope match-pop-market']
```

How can I get the current pages elem_href and not invisible other elements it seems to be picking up on other pages.

```
//div[@class='mpm_match_title' and .//div[@class='mpm_match_title style-scope match-pop-market']]//a[@class='style-scope match-pop-market']
```

Does not work though this should fix this issue in theory. Any ideas? Current output:

```
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
https://www.palmerbet.com/sports/soccer/italy-serie-b/match/6381070
https://www.palmerbet.com/sports/soccer/italy-serie-b/match/6386987
https://www.palmerbet.com/sports/soccer/italy-serie-b/match/6386988
https://www.palmerbet.com/sports/soccer/italy-serie-b/match/6386989
https://www.palmerbet.com/sports/soccer/italy-serie-b/match/6386990
https://www.palmerbet.com/sports/soccer/italy-serie-b/match/6386991
https://www.palmerbet.com/sports/soccer/italy-serie-b/match/6386992
https://www.palmerbet.com/sports/soccer/italy-serie-b/match/6387025
https://www.palmerbet.com/sports/soccer/italy-serie-b/match/6387026
https://www.palmerbet.com/sports/soccer/italy-serie-b/match/6387027
https://www.palmerbet.com/sports/soccer/italy-serie-b/match/6387028
```

Unable to wait for element as it wants to wait for the invisible elements not on that current page.

So:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'mpm_match_title')] #TEXT
//div[contains(@class, 'mpm_match_title style-scope match-pop-market')]  #BAR
//a[contains(@class, 'style-scope match-pop-market')] #HREF
style-scope match-pop-market
```

Combined:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'mpm_match_title') and .//div[contains(@class, 'mpm_match_title style-scope match-pop-market')]//a[@class='style-scope match-pop-market']
```

unable to find.

Desired output:

```
https://www.palmerbet.com/sports/soccer/italy-serie-b/match/6381070
https://www.palmerbet.com/sports/soccer/italy-serie-b/match/6386987
https://www.palmerbet.com/sports/soccer/italy-serie-b/match/6386988
https://www.palmerbet.com/sports/soccer/italy-serie-b/match/6386989
https://www.palmerbet.com/sports/soccer/italy-serie-b/match/6386990
https://www.palmerbet.com/sports/soccer/italy-serie-b/match/6386991
https://www.palmerbet.com/sports/soccer/italy-serie-b/match/6386992
https://www.palmerbet.com/sports/soccer/italy-serie-b/match/6387025
https://www.palmerbet.com/sports/soccer/italy-serie-b/match/6387026
https://www.palmerbet.com/sports/soccer/italy-serie-b/match/6387027
https://www.palmerbet.com/sports/soccer/italy-serie-b/match/6387028
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the code from the pastebin link in the comments, I basically just modified the Xpath to search for specific elements that would identify the links on the current page.

```
from random import shuffle

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.palmerbet.com/sports/soccer')

clickMe = wait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 
    ('//*[contains(@class,"filter_labe")]'))))
options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(@class,"filter_labe")]')

indexes = [index for index in range(len(options))]
shuffle(indexes)

xp = '//sport-match-grp[not(contains(@style, "display: none;"))]' \
    '//match-pop-market[@class="sport-match-grp" and ' \
    'not(contains(@style, "display: none;")) and ' \
    './/a[@id="match_link" and boolean(@href)]]'

for index in indexes:
    print(f'Loading index {index}')
    driver.get('https://www.palmerbet.com/sports/soccer')
    clickMe1 = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
        '(//ul[@id="tournaments"]//li//input)[%s]' % str(index + 1))))
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", clickMe1)
    clickMe1.click()

    try:
        # this attempts to find any links on the page
        clickMe = wait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((
            By.XPATH, xp)))
        elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xp)

        elem_href = []
        for elem in elems:
            print(elem.find_element_by_xpath('.//a[@id="match_link"]')
                .get_attribute('href'))
            elem_href.append(elem.get_attribute("href"))
    except:
        print(f'There are no matches in index {index}.')
```

Comment: The wait times do not work when you click the pages.  See: @Line28 clickMe = wait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ("//a[@class='style-scope match-pop-market']")))) https://pastebin.com/z8VPiPgc.  This creates better output but cannot get to output because its waiting for invisible elements not on page.

Comment: Note that it works for single pages and at first click.  After that, nada.

Comment: Thanks for showing me the code, I was a bit perplexed with the original request. Updating my response to reflect the new answer.

Comment: Also, just a heads, the England FA cup and the World Cup pages contain no links. The try / except is added to handle them when the wait fails.

Comment: You're a legend! :).  That works really well.  What would the xp selector be for #match_title (team name) which is present on each page.  That would mean all data is scraped and not some missing pages.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm silly :).  xp = '//sport-match-grp[not(contains(@style, "display: none;"))]' \
   '//match-pop-market[@class="sport-match-grp" and ' \
    'not(contains(@style, "display: none;")) and ' \
   './/*[@class="mpm_match_name style-scope match-pop-market" and boolean(@class)]]'  -- works nicely.